# Advanced Calc 1- Using Partial Sum to Show Property

Tags: analysis

[image]

The problem above is a homework problem so I kindly ask no one write up a solution. I only want feedback on my attempt at a solution to see if I am going down the right path. I want to know if I am using partial sums correctly.

My attempt was the following: Break this up into two cases: When the $Nth$ partial sum term is odd and when it is even. When $N$ is odd, set $N= 2M + 1$. $$s_N = s_{2M+1}$$
$$L \le S_{2M+1} + a_{2M+2}$$
$$\Rightarrow L-S_{2M+1} \le a_{2M+2}$$ 
But since $L \ge S_{2M+1}$ $\Rightarrow |S_{2M+1} - L| \le a_{2M+2}$ $\Rightarrow |S_{N} - L| \le a_{N+1}$. 
And then I would use a similar argument when $N$ is even. Does this look good?

Comment: But, how do you justify the inequality $L\leq S_{2M+1}+a_{2M+2}$?

Comment: The way I'd think to justify it is that $L = S_{2M+1} + a_{2M+2} - a_{2M+3} + ...$ 
The sum of the terms past $a_{2M+2}$ add up to give a negative quantity and only decrease the value of L. Should more details need to be given?

Comment: I think that more details are needed. What you are mentioning in your comment is the core of the proof.

Comment: Okay, I will work on the details. Just wanted to know that I was on the right track here. Thank you!